# C# list items to database SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, list

Hello I have a simple question that regards inserting data into a MS MySql Database 2012 table. The table that I have is called COMPLETED and has 3 fields.

- student_ID (int, NOT allowed nulls)
- completed (bool, NOT allowed nulls)
- random_code (string, allowed nulls)

In c# I have a list filled with unique random codes. I want all codes inserted into the database, so if I have 20 records I want 20 unique codes inserted into the random_code field. So the first records gets the first code, the seconds records gets the second code and so on. I think the best way to do this is using a foreach and, for each code in the list of codes insert that code into the random_code field in my database. The problem is I don't know how to do this. I have the following code that give's me an error at VALUE:

Incorrect syntax near 'VALUE'.

```
        foreach (string unRaCo in codes)
        {
            //insert database
            SqlCommand toDB = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO COMPLETED (random_code) VALUE ( '"+ unRaCo +"' ) ", conn);
            SqlDataReader toDBR;
            toDBR = toDB.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

Could anyone give me a dircetion here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Okay I totally changed my query as I figured out it did not yet do what I wanted it to do. I now want to update my records instead of inserting records. I did that with the following code:

```
        foreach (string unRaCo in codes)
        {
            //insert database
            SqlCommand naarDB = new SqlCommand("UPDATE VOLTOOID SET random_code = '"+ unRaCo +"'  ", connectie);
            SqlDataReader naarDBR;
            naarDBR = naarDB.ExecuteReader();
            naarDBR.Close();
        }
```

The problem this time is that the update query updates ALL records with the first code, so the first record has the code 12345 for example but all other records also have that code. I want to update 12345 into record 1 and 54321 for example in number 2, how do I do that?

Comment: You better ask separate questions as it will make answers clearer...

Comment: Okay I'll make another one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct is `Values` not `Value`, even if you only provide one column.

About your edit. First of all beware of SQL Injection. You better use SQLParameter class. Check [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) for further info.

If you want to update a specific id then use a where clause like (in plain SQL):

```
UPDATE VOLTOOID SET random_code = @NewValue WHERE random_code = @OldValue
```

Now if you just want to add the random number in a specific row, then you would have to use some more advanced SQL functions. Again in plain SQL you would have:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT random_code,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY random_code) AS ROWSEQ -- This will give a unique row number to each row of your table
    FROM   VOLTOOID _code
)
UPDATE MyCTE 
SET    random_code = @NewValue 
WHERE  ROWSEQ = @YourRandomRow
```

As the above queries are for SQL script execution you will need to define the variable used.

Comment: or by removing Values and instead using Select

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, you are using 'value' where you should use 'values'. If you have SSMS you will able to easily figure out this kind of errors.

Usually I create the query in SQL Server Management Studio query editor, then use it in C#. Most of the times I use SQL Server stored procedures where it's possible. Because I think it cost some extra resources to execute a text query than executing a procedure

Comment: This is a **myth** - but it's wrong. A well-defined, **parametrized query** has exactly the same performance behavior as a stored procedure.....