# UPDATE every record in SQL database from list

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, list

Hello I have a simple question that regards updating data into a MS MySql Database 2012 table. The table that I have is called COMPLETED and has 3 fields. 
student_ID (int, NOT allowed nulls)
completed (bool, NOT allowed nulls)
random_code (string, allowed nulls)

In c# I have a list filled with unique random codes. I want all codes updated into the database, so if I have 20 records I want 20 unique codes updated into the random_code field. So the first records gets the first code, the seconds records gets the second code and so on. I think the best way to do this is using a foreach and, for each code in the list of codes update that code into the random_code field in my database.

```
    foreach (string unRaCo in codes)
    {
        //insert database
        SqlCommand toDB = new SqlCommand("UPDATE COMPLETED SET random_code = '"+ unRaCo +"'  ", conn);
        SqlDataReader toDBR;
        toDBR = toDB.ExecuteReader();
        toDBR.Close();
    }
```

The problem I have is that the update query updates ALL records with the first code, so the first record has the code 12345 for example but all other records also have that code. I want to update 12345 into record 1 and 54321 for example in number 2, how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify - is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: Wasn't this solved in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704150/c-sharp-list-items-to-database-sql/19704222#comment29269132_19704222

Comment: use foreach and a where clause?

Comment: @Westie: Why did you delete your answer? I think it is the correct answer.

Comment: @Kaf - not really; the real answer here is that nothing needs to be done. Each student, if an incremental value is used, technically has a random code already assigned.  I suppose this is more of an issue with the original design of the database than the query used to supply the random data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UPDATE query is missing the WHERE keyword, and you have to use the StudentID in it.

Something like this:

```
"UPDATE COMPLETED SET random_code = '"+ unRaCo +"'  "+"WHERE student_ID ="+ _studentidvariable_
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a Hashtable with `studentID` as the Key and the `code` as the value.
For each entry (student) in the Hashtable would be a unique code.

Then you could just do:

```
 UPDATE COMPLETED SET random_code = (the code provided by hashtable) WHERE student_id = (Hashtable KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be an accepted answer now. Nonetheless, this should do it with only the codes loop.

```
var count = 0;
foreach (string unRaCo in codes)
{
    //insert database
    SqlCommand toDB = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE c SET c.random_code = '" + unRaCo +"'
    FROM COMPLETED c
    JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student_ID) AS number,
    Student_ID FROM COMPLETED) num ON num.student_ID = c.student_id
    WHERE num.number = " + count, conn);
    SqlDataReader toDBR;
    toDBR = toDB.ExecuteReader();
    toDBR.Close();
    count++;
}
```